# Looking for an ebook about a telepathic woman and telepathic twin brothers

Tags: story-identification, telepathy

I am looking for an e-book which I read about a high level telepathic woman who works as a mediator in government service. Her work is basically to mediate negotiations between parties as she can easily read minds and check if any of the negotiating party is cheating or lying.

In the middle of one of the negotiations, a male telepath intruded into her mind and they were talking to each other in their minds and the man sexually approached her in the telepathic conversation. Later the woman found out the man has a twin who is also a high level telepath, but he is currently hiding his ability to avoid being detected by the government. Both twin brothers visited the woman in a telepathic dream that night and they were talking, became closer and had sex in the dream.

The woman later was sent by the government to join an investigation - she was told to do psychometry on the items found in a crime scene. Somehow when she tried to do psychometry on a book, there was a mental attack set on her and she fell into the trap. She immediately lost consciousness and dreamt of her childhood about being abused by her father. The twin brothers later saved her by going into the depth of her consciousness and pulled her out from the dream.

Can anyone please help me identify this book? I read it many years back and eager to read it again. I couldn't find it anywhere. Thank you very much in advance.